# Structuring Django apps

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a Django web application consisting of following parts:

1. API (Django-REST-Framework) *Finished*
2. Custom administration page *Unfinished*

   1. For super users
   2. For normal users

The API app which has currently been finished has all the models for the entire system hence it made most sense. Now what i'm very uncertain about is if i should build the administration page inside of the API app, or create a separate app for that purpose? I will still need to refer to an external model, and will this be painless to maintain in the future?

I am not fully certain how the app structuring should be handled in my certain use-case.

Comment: Create an separate app, it will allow you to modify parts of it easier in the future, without requiring to mess with either sides.
It still will have dependencies on it, but on the other hand both of your apps were build for each other.

Comment: I agree with the other comment posted here.  Leave your REST API as a separate app from your administration app.  This not only allows you to modify your REST API without changing your administration app, but will allow you to create other apps (think mobile and web interfaces) that consume the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to advises i ended up creating separate apps to keep clean structure in the code.